# Generate random string to match a specific pattern

Tags: python, random

```
import random
import string


def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(y))


p1 = str(random.randrange(1, 99))
p2 = str(random_char(5))
p3 = str(random.randrange(1, 9))
p4 = str(random_char(2))
p5 = str(random.randrange(1, 9))
p6 = str(random_char(1))  # Y
p7 = str(random.randrange(1, 9))  # 7
p8 = str(random_char(3))  # AUS
result = p1 + p2+p3+p4+p5+p6+p7+p8
print(result)
```

I generate a specific code like "31SPZVG2CZ2R8WFU" How can i do it in a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you want this to be `1-2 digits + 5*random uppercased letters + ...` or it can be any random string?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I model 31SPZVG2CZ2R8WFU this key as example.  So digits+strs.. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `random_char` function, you don't use `x` at all. Replace it with `_` (it's conventional in python to use `_` for throwaway variables). `y` could also be renamed to something more descriptive. The name of the function could also be renamed to `random_chars` since you're generating one or more of them.

Also, use string formatting instead of all those extra variables:

```
def generate_key():
    return (f"{random.randrange(1, 9)}{random_chars(5)}{random.randrange(1, 9)}{random_chars(2)}" 
            f"{random.randrange(1, 9)}{random_chars(1)}{random.randrange(1, 9)}{random_chars(3)}")
```

Note that the f-strings are available for Python versions >= 3.6

As a side note, there's this nice [exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex) which can:

> Generate all - or random - matching strings to a given regular
> expression and more. It's pure python, without external dependencies.

Given some pattern (similar to what you want):

```
r"(\d[A-Z]{1,4}){4}"
```

- `(...){4}` matches the previous token exactly 4 times.
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
- `[A-Z]{1,4}` matches the previous token between 1 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `A-Z` matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

*Note: I'm not a regex expert so there might be an easier / more correct version of this.*

I think you can use this regex which returns exactly the pattern you want: `\d{1,2}[A-Z]{5}\d[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]{1}\d[A-Z]{3}`

Your entire code could be rewritten as:

```
import exrex

random_key = exrex.getone(r'(\d[A-Z]{1,4}){4}')
print(random_key)
```

Which would generate:

```
'3C2BBV3NGKJ2XYJ'
```

For more information about regular expressions feel free to search on the internet to get familiar with them. For tests, I usually use [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: As an advice, before accepting an answer try to wait 1-2 days to see alternative solutions/improvements.

Comment: Is this right? The pattern you're using doesn't seem to follow the OP's, for instance having two leading digits.

Comment: @Reinderien It's just an example. I've specified in my answer that this regex might not be as the one in the question. And with a bit of effort from OP it can be easily modified/customized. More, that is an alternate solution for OP to have in mind ^^. //L.E: added a similar regex

Answer (score 3):

Instead of treating number and letter parts differently, you could use `random.choice` for both and save some code:

```
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase

spec = [
    range(1, 99), *[ascii_uppercase] * 5,
    range(1, 9), *[ascii_uppercase] * 2,
    range(1, 9), *[ascii_uppercase],
    range(1, 9), *[ascii_uppercase] * 3,
]
print(''.join(str(random.choice(pool)) for pool in spec))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9BCsIwEEX3OcXsTEooaBHswpOUIiWm7YjNDJO48PQxRVcFobP6MO9/ePxOM4XmwpIzLkySQIZwp0WNQgvEJBgm@H2G6BBvL2YvboheqcjewRU6BeVKb/L6aKFtjYWq29A9VHC2G/IfeNoF7l1rrOoVF5OkD4f6QRh0EdNf0drNhM5rJnoaAyMJrBEwwKpnTM4f)

Comment: Wow, cool. Could you please explain how this code works exactly? I am just learning

Comment: It just builds a list of sequences (try `print(spec)`) and then picks an element from each and concatenates them all.